# How to iterate through all properties and its values in Typescript class

Tags: typescript, object-properties

How do I iterate through list of class properties and get the values of each (only the properties and not the functions)

```js
class Person{
 name:string;
 age:number;
 address:Address;
 getObjectProperties(){
   let json = {};
    // I need to get the name, age and address in this JSON and return it
    // how to do this dynamically, rather than getting one by one 
    // like json["name"] = this.name;
   return json;
 }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, if you look at the compiled code of:

```
class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: Address;
}
```

You'll see that those properties aren't part of it:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person() {
    }
    return Person;
}());
```

Only if you assign a value then the property is added:

```
class Person {
    name: string = "name";
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person() {
        this.name = "name";
    }
    return Person;
}());
```

You can use a [property decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am making the assumption that you have assigned values to your fields like `name`. If that is not the case this will not work.

```
// if you want json as a string
getObjectProperties(){
   let json = JSON.stringify(this);
}
```

or

```
// if you want a copy of the fields and their values
getObjectProperties(){
   let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
}
```

or if you want to loop through the properties see duplicate [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)